# Android AppBar not showing shadow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, material-design, android-actionbar-compat

The AppBar and BottomNavigationView don't display any shadow on the listview between them even with

```
setSupportActionBar().setElevation(3.0f);
```

I have the following layout

```
CordinatorLayout
--LinearLayout

----AppBarLayout
-----------Toolbar
----/AppBarLayout

----FrameLayout
-----------ListView
----/FrameLayout

----BottomNavigationView

--/LinearLayout
/CordinatorLayout
```

what are the other possibilities the shadow isn't drawn

**Edit**,

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

older devices like Galaxy s3 running Android 4.4.2 still doesn't show any shadow, even with hardware acceleration enabled

Comment: set elevation in AppbarLayout xml.

Comment: it's for API 21 and above, I want it for all versions

Comment: add app:elevation="4dp" it work with lower versions

Comment: used android:elevation="4dp" but unfortunately here also I get this warning "Attribute elevation is only used in API 21 and higher.(Current min is 9)

Comment: use app:elevation="4dp" not android:elevation="4dp"

Comment: whats the namespace for app ? it shows error 'namespace app not bound'

Comment: xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: nope, doesn't work

Comment: what error occured?

Comment: no error, the code has no effect

Comment: try to add above code in toolbar instead appbarlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue wasn't related to toolbar elevation, view clipping or incorrect layouts, the manifest entry for this particular activity had hardware acceleration turned off.

```
<activity
..
..
..
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
```

changing this to `true` fixed it